# Can the following equation be solved without knowing the constants $C_i$?

Tags: polynomials

Presume I have an equation of the form:

$$F(x) = \sum_{i=1}^nC_i(a_ix + b_i) = 0$$

If it is known that $C_i \ne 0 \forall i$, is it possible to find $x$ without knowing the value of any of the $C_i$?

Comment: Nope, this is - without further knowledge - not possible.

Comment: Hm, oh well.  Thanks